# Convert recorded movie to GIF on iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller, gif, file-conversion

I'm building an iOS app which requires me to allow the users to record a 15sec clip (with UIImagePickerController for example) and then convert it into an animated GIF. How could I achieve this? Is there any library/framework available for such task?

Thanks!

Comment: AVFoundation, CoreMedia and CoreVideo, furthermore http://ffmpeg.org

Comment: As far as I know about GIF files, I'd need to get all the frames of the video and stick them together on a GIF file, but I don't really know how can this be achieved

Comment: Hi pmerino, Did you get any solution for the above question? I am also looking for the same. Post your solution here and help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a library called Regift for converting movies to gifs on iOS. It's available [on Github](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift). Hopefully this helps you :)

If you install it, you can then do

```
Regift.createGIFFromURL(videoURL, withFrameCount: frameCount, delayTime: delayTime, loopCount: loopCount)
```

to create a gif.

It's best to check the full documentation, as I'll be keeping that up to date more than this answer.

Comment: Just tried it, looks like it could work with my project!